# Jquery to max number from a set of divs

Tags: jquery

Given the following HTML

```
<div class"myclass">10</div>
<div class"myclass">25</div>
<div class"myclass">50</div>
<div class"myclass">20</div>
```

I want Jquery to return the maximum value found on divs with class:"myclass". (This is 50)

I thought of using .find.text() will be a good starting point but cant figure out exactly how,

Help is greatly appreciatted,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, something like

```
var $set = $('myclass'),
    max  = 0;
$.each($set, function(){
    if(parseInt(this.text()) > max)
       max = parseInt(this.text());
});
```

should do it.

Answer (score 2):

My shot at it:

```
var max = 0;
$("div.myclass").each(function(){
    var value = parseInt($(this).text())
    if(value > max) max = value;
});
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var max = 0;
$('.myclass').each(function(){
    thisVal = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
    if(thisVal > max) max = thisVal;
});
alert(max);
```

Comment: When you use `parseInt` you should set the radix to 10, for this case: `thisVal = parseInt($(this).text(),10);`